# Why does the script debugger in Microsoft Visual Studio not work for me

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer

I am using Visual Studio 2008, when I start up an Asp.net project that starts IE6, I do not see any jscript file in the “Script Document” folder in the Solution.

[alt text http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/8338/example1t.png](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/8338/example1t.png)

However if I start up IE by hand and point it at my website, then attach the Visual Studio 2008 debugger to IE, it does show the jscript files in the “Script Document”.  **However the list of files in “Script Document" is not updated when I move to another page.**

[alt text http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/6198/example2f.png](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/6198/example2f.png)

So I know that debugger must be turned on in IE etc.  **What is going on?**

I have just created a new Asp.net project with a single page that just contains one control and I have got the same result.

All the files are hosted on the same machine as Visual Studio and IE.

See my answer for what solved this for me, other people *may* find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658912/reenabling-javascript-debugger-in-ie7-with-visual-studio-2008) usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I uninstalled VS 2008
- I then did a clean install of VS 2008 and it did not work
- I then decided to install VS 2008 SP1 so that I could get on with some other work
- The install of SP1 needed a reboot (the uninstall / install of VS 2008 did not need a reboot)
- **The script debugger started to work.**

I still don't know what caused the problem and lost over a day's work with it.  How long before the script debugger stops working again..

Answer (score 1):

If the control is hosted on a different machine you need to use that method to debug. See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2006/01/13/512496.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for you help, however, all the files are hosted on the same machine as Visual Studio and IE.  I have updated my question to include this information.