# (Re)Enabling JavaScript debugger in IE7 with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, internet-explorer

Visual Studio 2008 comes with nice javascript debugging features.

But I have played a little with NetBeans debugger wich has installed an ugly Script Debugger from Microsoft to my IE... Normally IE should ask what do I want to use for debugging, but now I can't start debugging with Visual Studio, the Script Debugger is started automatically... After uninstalling the Script Debugger I can't debug in IE at all. Even attaching to iexplore.exe process doesn't helps...

Has installed the Script Debugger again... :(((((

How can I get back my Visual Studio debugging working in IE again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem. It's not quite resolved yet, but I'll share what I have.

To let IE see the debugger again do this:
 1. Open Visual Studio.
 2. Go to Tools > Options > Debugging > Just-In-Time.
 3. Enable Script checkbox, click OK.
 4. Close Visual Studio.

Now when I try to debug it opens Visual Studio but gives this error:
"Unable to attach to the crashing process. An error occurred that usually indicates a corrupt installation (code 0x80040155). If the problem persists, repair your Visual Studio installation via 'Add or Remove Program' in Control Panel."

When I get back in the office tomorrow I'll try repairing Visual Studio.

Comment: I changed settings in Visual Studio and now it works! I don't get the error you mentioned about.... But I have installed Script Debugger before again...

Answer (score 4):

make sure you don't have script debugging disabled in IE Settings. May not be the answer to your situation but I forget this all the time.

[image: IE7 Tools - Internet Options - Advanced]

Answer (score 0):

[How to debug Windows Script Host, VBScript, and JScript files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308364). Especially

> make sure that the following registry
>   key is set to 1:
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script\Settings\JITDebug`

Comment: The poster explicitly mentions IE, and this registry setting is only relevant for WSH and friends, not IE. Same goes for the KB article.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a global error handler **window.onError**, this handler prevents JS errors from being caught and IE does not asks if we want to debut with VS.

As another alternative, you can attach VS to IE process, then put breakpoints within any JS script that is available in resources view. VS should display (Script,x86) next to IE process in process list, if script is not in list it means that you haven't properly unchecked "Disable script debugging" as mentioned by @Jon Erickson

Answer (score 0):

IE (7) Tools -> Manage Add-ons -> Enable or Disable Add-ons...:
Disable the troubling debuggers.